# 'es' - no return tags (sitemaps)

Tags: hreflang

Google webmaster gives the following error for my website
Sitemap provided URLs and alternate URLs in 'es' that do not have return tags.

```
Originating URL     
/welcome-to-the-neighborhood/   
/vendor-sign-up/
/services/senior-citizen-moving/
```

Alternate URL

```
https://www.jensenmovingandstorage.com/es/welcome-to-the-neighborhood/
https://www.jensenmovingandstorage.com/es/vendor-sign-up/
https://www.jensenmovingandstorage.com/es/services/senior-citizen-moving/
```

Please see attached image and let me know how to fix this error

[image]

Comment: That's strange, I checked and everything seems fine. Did you make any changes after the error popup? try "inspect URL" in the new Google Search Console.

Comment: I did not do any change after the error popup OK I will inspect url

Comment: I inspected the URL in New version of Google webmaster tool and all is OK but old version of Google webmaster tool still shows hreflang errors.. please let me know how to remove these errors

Comment: Inspect URL tool of GSC is something new so it's more accurate than any messages we could have in the old version of GSC.

If you want to double check, use Google Analytics (or your data system) to check if visitors are going to the correct language site. Check entry pages for bounce rate or country/language problems.

If you don't find anything strange, everything is fine.